# BrowserComponent doesn't work on CodenameOne 3.7.2?

Tags: codenameone

the following code doesn't work in the Simulator (on NetBeans 8.2 + CodenameOne 3.7.2 + Skin Iphone3gs) and doesn't work in my Android 4.1.2 device. It blocks the Simulator and it shows a blank screen on the real device (with a blinking "Loading..."). What's the problem? Thank you

```
import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class Gmail {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Form title Example", new BorderLayout());
        BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
        browser.setURL("https://students.uninettunouniversity.net/");
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted the `hi.show()` line at the end

Comment: Oh, my distraction!
However, why is the behaviour in the simulator different from the behaviour in the real device? On Android the website (that is Gmail) works correctly and remembers my account, on the simulator the page doesn't allow me to do the login.

Comment: On the desktop we use a desktop browser which is what we have available. We can't simulate HTML with complete accuracy to the device.